# posting to facebook with multi-line message as opposed to short 1-liners

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to post to my facebook wall with the code pictured below, however, carriage returns (line feeds) are not being honored / allowed in the "@message" value.  See the errors in xcode below.  When I use backslash '' at the end of lines to escape the linefeed, the post is made but the result is unreadable.

How do I post a multi-line body of content for a facebook post?

Better yet, my actual original content has html markup in it for such things as bold, etc...   Is there any way to post to facebook with any sort of richer text?

Many thanks.

Phil

see image at: https://skitch.com/aibkwik/8iuxt/fb4.xcodeproj-fb-viewcontroller.m

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"removed for privacy", @"app_id",
                               @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/golf-whiz/removed?ls=1&mt=8", @"link",
                               @"https://img.skitch.com/20120424-mauaru649ed4i4igqc8mtth6bh.png", @"picture",
                                @"Golf Whiz", @"name",
                                @"Check this out!", @"caption",
                                @"Summary Information\nSouth Riding GC\nShots fired: 13\nFarts cut: 10", @"description",nil];

  [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your NSString in Xcode should only be one line. To represent line breaks, you should use `\n`. The message you are looking for is:

```
@"Summary Information\nSouth Riding GC\nShots fired: 13\nFarts cut: 10";
```

Someone else had this problem and it seems maybe [the second answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701609/how-insert-linebreaks-in-nsstring-for-facebook-stream-publish) here found a solution.

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that I tried that...  Get same line wrapping result as shown in this image: https://skitch.com/aibkwik/8iu58/ios-simulator

Comment: I've updated original post to include a source listing of what I'm using.  Thanks for any further help.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link

Comment: nope, funny enough, all that did was reverse the two lines that were each listed as properties - and then ran them together without a line feed.  Can't believe this is so hard.

Comment: Well, to be correct...  It does post the 'properties' rows with each on its own line, just as I desire.  However, the lines are delivered to facebook in reverse order...  Sending a paragraph of text from the bottom is somewhat underwhelming for the target user.   :(